# Change the default window size of the Windows Volume Mixer

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio, volume-mixer

is there a way to set the default size of the Windows Volume Mixer? When I open it up it shows up very small with a scrollbar at the bottom, like this (German UI):

[image]

So I have to scroll a lot, or adjust the window size, every time I open it. Since I use this a lot, because I have to do volume adjustments to single applications very often, this is quite bothersome. If would be great, if every time I opened this, it would just list all applications without a scrollbar, or it would at least remember the window size I set it to the last time I used it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Windows 10, most windows of this type **do not** allow width changes. There is no proper way to do so.

However, you can use an app on the Windows store called [EarTrumpet](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/eartrumpet/9nblggh516xp), which give you a system tray icon that lists all your applications from top to bottom.

[image: EarTrumpet Snapshot]

It allows you to change your audio device through its right-click context menu. I think this will solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Can be achieved with [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com/download/) script:

```
SetTitleMatchMode, RegEx

WinTitle=Volume Mixer.*

X=0
Y=0
Width = %A_ScreenWidth%

Run, SndVol.exe

Loop {
    Sleep, 100

    If (WinExist(WinTitle)) {
        break
    }
}

WinActivate, %WinTitle%
WinMove, %WinTitle%,, %X%, %Y%, %Width%
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to run PowerShell commands to change the volume.

Save the commands as a .ps1 file and use Group Policy to set it as a login script.

Detailed commands here:

Windows 10 registry setting for volume control [duplicate]

http://superuser.com/questions/984459/windows-10-registry-setting-for-volume-control